# How to get an output from exec?

Tags: php

I tried different variations of `exec`:

```
exec('which ffmpeg', $output, $e);
exec("which ffmpeg", $output);
exec('which ffmpeg 2>&1', $output, $e);
exec('echo "which ffmpeg" 2>&1', $output, $e);
$output = exec('which ffmpeg');
```

But no luck.

In console:

```
[root@gs01]# which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: So you've read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php , but it didn't work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Pass array as second argument to `exec()` method:

```
$output = array();
exec('which ffmpeg', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

For more information check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

---

```
php > $a = array(); exec('which ffmpeg', $a); var_dump($a);
```

Returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(15) "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`system()` might do what you want.

```
ob_start();
system('ls 2>&1');
$ob_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


echo $ob_contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo shell_exec('which ffmpeg');
```

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns the output as string.